# ordering in bash "for" loop

Tags: bash, unix, sorting

Is there any way to control the sorting that occurs when I run a,
for i in * ; do; echo $i; done;
in my directory. 
It seems to always use ascii sorting. Anyway to do a numeric sort?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use sort(1) and its numeric sort:

```
for i in $(ls -1 * | sort -n) ; do echo $i ; done
```

Comment: So is `*`.  Actually, no, it's not redundant; it will list the contents of subdirectories, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The `-1` forces single-column output, but that happens anyway when the output of `ls` goes to a pipe.  What might be beneficial is a `-d` to list directories without listing the contents of the directory.

Comment: looping through $(ls -1 *) is problematic. If a filename uses a space or newline you will get funky (or even disastrous) results.

Comment: See also [useless use of `ls`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls) and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs; the simple fix is something like `printf '%s\n' * | sort -n | while IFS= read -r i; do ...` though that too will fail if you have file names with newlines in them.

Answer (score 7):

How about making your filenames so they sort naturally as numbers, i.e. padded with leading zeros. Instead of `1 .. 10 .. 100`, use `001 ..010 .. 100`?

To include sub-directories:

```
for i in $( ls -d * | sort -n ); do echo $i; done;
```

To exclude sub-directories:

```
for i in $( ls | sort -n ); do echo $i; done;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @samdy1 : Thanks for the endits. you're right. What was I thinking of!? ;-) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ordering from ls [sorting options] that you give for the directory with
i.e.

```
      for i in `ls -X` ; do
             echo $i
      done
```

first the ls command with a certain sorting is executed, in the example case sorting for extension then you give out the the list with a for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in $(ls | sort -n) ; do echo $i ; done
```